# JavaScript Anonymous Function With Parameters From Call()

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

I am trying to do the following:

```
function main(callback) {
   $.ajax('server-side', function() {
       this.callback.call("hello");
   }.bind({ callback: callback });
}

main(function(response) {
   alert(response);
});
```

Response is `undefined`, I would expect it to be `"hello"`. Any ideas why?

Comment: you wrote "print response" , but print doesnt exist in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`call` first argument should be a reference to "this". Being "this" the context where you want to execute your function.
[Call function Mozila MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: You can omit the .call part and just say this.callback("hello"). And you can omit all of the bind stuff and just use the callback parameter directly as callback("hello").

Answer (score 1):

You wrote :

```
function main(callback) {
   $.ajax('server-side', function() {
       this.callback.call("hello");
   }.bind({ callback: callback });
}

main(function(response) {
   print response;
});
```

print doesnt exists in javascript.

then you wrote this.callback.call , which is wrong

you should write

```
callback.call(this,"hello") ,
```

just check the call function signature.

Comment: Actually need `this` because of the bind() and bindding an object containing the callback. Need to use bind() because by the time the callback fires from the ajax event the passed in parameter `callback` will be out of scope.

Comment: @Justin - the main() function's callback parameter will still be accessible when the ajax callback runs, _even though main() will have finished by then_, due to the magic of closures. Try it and see...